# Processing a flat file with multiple formats and different sets of records in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to process a Pipped separated flat file using SSIS. The file has two different types of records. each record set has has different it's own header row and a trailer row. They need to go to two different table.

The trailer row has the row count for each record set while the header row contains column names for the records. So in essence it's like two types of files but in one file.

I've tried several solutions including using a conditional split but I haven't been able to achieve this. I know you could do this using a script component and C# but I haven't been able to achieve this. I've attached an image to show file format.

This is what I have tried so far.

1. I edited the flat file connection to ragged right so that the output comes in one column.
2. I then created a script component as source. The idea was to read the file line by line using stream reader, then create 4 output buffers. 2 for column headers and 2 for the different detail rows then set the script to stop when it reaches the trailer row. My intention was to merge each header row the respective detail rows then save them to the relevant tables
3. I then used C# code which I got from my research. I picked this up from the Microsoft site.

I used the Code Below:

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private StreamReader textReader;
    private string RTWFile;

    public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
    {
        IDTSConnectionManager100 connMgr = this.Connections.RTWCon;
        RTWFile = (string)connMgr.AcquireConnection(null);
    }

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        textReader = new StreamReader(RTWFile);
    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        string nextLine;
        string[] columns;

        char[] delimiters;
        delimiters = "|".ToCharArray();

        nextLine = textReader.ReadLine();
        while (nextLine != null)
        {
            columns = nextLine.Split(delimiters);
            {
                HeadersBuffer.AddRow();
                HeadersBuffer.EmployeeNumber = columns[0];
                HeadersBuffer.LegacyStaffID = columns[1];
                HeadersBuffer.FirstName = columns[2];
                HeadersBuffer.LastName = columns[3];
                HeadersBuffer.PassportIssuingCountry = columns[4];
                HeadersBuffer.PassportType = columns[5];
                HeadersBuffer.PassportNumber = columns[6];
                HeadersBuffer.PassportIssuingAuthority =columns[7];           
                HeadersBuffer.PassportIssueDate = columns[8];
                HeadersBuffer.PassportExpirationDate = columns[9];
            }
            nextLine = textReader.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        textReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Image of the flat file format:

[image: Image of the flat file format]

OutPutBuffers:

[image: OutPutBuffers]

FlatFileConfiguration:

[image: FlatFileConfiguration]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51946813/edit) and show us the code that you tried, because without that you are a lot less likely to receive answers. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: Post test instead of a picture. You can  post more data.  I can do it in a few minutes.

Comment: Also the example in the image is inconsistent, possibly even wrong: (1) there are **duplicate column names** in the 1st row. (2) The first row has **5 column headers**, the second row has **6 data values**. You need to do better.

Comment: @Peter  : Do not think you are correct.  Seen lots if text input file that look exactly like the posted sample.  This file probably dates back to the 1970's.

Comment: @PeterB. My appologies for not posting more info. I am fairly new in SO. I've added more info and sample code. As for the file formart. it's the correct format. I actually receive it in that exact format.

Comment: @jdweng I've added more infor. Please let me know if that helps. i really appreciate your helpd. I've also attached more images of my  script task configuration. Thanks

Comment: Below is a sample file format. The file is pipped separated . 

ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD|ColumnE
Test|Test1|Test2|Test3|Test
TotalRowCount|1
ColumnF|ColumnG|ColumnH
Test|Test1|Test2
TotalRow2Count|1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to extract the information from Trailer rows also?

Separating the file into two files is the cleanest way to do this. We can do this with a script task once we understand your requirements.

UPDATE:

Add Script Task and Provide FilePath as Read Variable

Edit Script task and add these to namespaces region at the top

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        String InputFilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();
        string InputFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(InputFilePath);
        string TrailerLine = "TotalRow";
        bool FirstFile = true;
        string line;
        List<string> FirstFileLines, SecondFileLines;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(InputFilePath);
        FirstFileLines = new List<string>();
        SecondFileLines = new List<string>();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(TrailerLine))
            {
                FirstFile = false;
                continue;
            }

            if (FirstFile) FirstFileLines.Add(line);
            else SecondFileLines.Add(line);
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(InputFolder + @"\FirstFile.txt", FirstFileLines.ToArray());
        File.WriteAllLines(InputFolder + @"\SecondFile.txt", SecondFileLines.ToArray());
        file.Close();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks DIWP. I don't need the traillers. I can discard them. The most import thing is the Column headers rows and the details rows

Comment: How big can the file get? Also, is "TotalRowCount" the actual string in trailer line?

Comment: After the above script task, you can have two dataflows to take care of importing the 2 files to their tables respectively. hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this out.I'll let you know how it goes. The file won't be so big. I think the most I can receive per day is about 50,000 records which is manageable. AS for the trailers, one is Total Visa Count and the other one is Total Passport Count. I could add a separate variable to handle the 2nd trailer.Thanks once again DIWP

Comment: Thanks DIWP. Your script worked like a charm. Thanks so much